Refresh materialized concurrently suddenly stopped working
I have about 10 materialized views that get refreshed every day. One of them actually every 10 minutes
The problem is that suddenly, the concurrently stopped working. I get the following error
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for schema ogr_system_tables
Where: PL/pgSQL function ogr_system_tables.event_trigger_function_for_metadata() line 8 at 
SQL statement
SQL statement "DROP TABLE pg_temp_63.pg_temp_39246664_2, pg_temp_63.pg_temp_39246664"

This is a very strange permission error, since I am using an admin account. Even If I grant myself permission on that schema and try again, the error does not go away. I tried rebooting the database and it still does not work
The bizarre thing is that if I refresh those views without using the concurrently, it works fine. Problem is that many tables get accessed constantly so the concurrently is needed

What version (major and minor)?

Does that function have a security definer?

@RonJohn PostgreSQL 13.15

It also looks like a system function so I'm not sure how to check it

It looks like a site-specific "system function", not a Postgresql system function.
